# syntax for selecting the last recordset in my model

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3

I tried different possibilities but nothing worked, in the tutorial I couldn't find an example either.

I have a method in my modelclass:

```
    public function getlastImport($filename)
{
    //$id = (int) $id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['Path' => $filename]);
    $row = $rowset->current();
    if (! $row) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
                ));
    }

    return $row;
}
```

I want to retrieve the last import of a given filename, so ist must be like in sql:

```
select max(ID) from table where filename = $filename;
```

But how would be the right syntax in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql query should be

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE filename={$filename} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Use as the following in your model

```
public function getlastImport($filename)
{

    $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
    $select->columns(array('id', 'filename', 'label'));
    $select->where(array('filename' => $filename));
    $select->order("id DESC");
    $select->limit(1);

    $result = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    $row = $result->current();

    if (! $row) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
            'Could not find row with identifier %d',
            $id
        ));
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: the question was, how to write it in my model.

Comment: it worked, thanks fpr the syntax, I was searching for implementing the rowfunction max, this ist quite easiert